# What top 10 items did the teams on the TV survival show Alone most frequently choose?

Tags: gear, survival

This a question about the [outdoor survival show Alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alone_(TV_series)). The teams are allowed to choose [10 items from a list of 40](https://www.history.com/shows/alone/articles/gear-list).

Currently season 5 has aired as of this writing, I have never seen the show, but wonder what items that teams most often choose to bring, from the list of 40?

Comment: Isn't this more of a media/tv question? If it was opinion based it would be better suited for this stack exchange.

Comment: @Monster ["In the edge case where the question is appropriate on more than one site, leave it on both sites and let the users of each community benefit from the information." Source Robert Cartaino at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/4713#4713) The question is never, is there another site for the question, it is always is the question in scope at this site?

Comment: @Sue I was hoping that the 5 year span would provided a good overview, presumably some learned from the experiences of others.

Comment: @JamesJenkins If you are planning on using this information to influence your own choices of survival gear, you should note that (despite what the channel claims) the contestants are not all survival experts. Some of the contestants have left on the first day or two, not being able to cope with real survival. Some have left within the first few weeks because they can't catch any food or don't know what is edible. That said, some of them are good at it, but the gear list may be skewed by those who aren't.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Survival Skills Alone Gear List](http://survivalskills.guide/alone-gear-list/), the most frequently chosen were sleeping bag (100%); ferro rod (100%); fishing kit with line (96%); 2 quart pot (91%), knife (89%); ax (87%), saw (85%), food (77%).

After that there's a significant drop before the rest, which include gill net (45%); paracord (43%); 12x12 tarp (34%); Bow and 6 arrows (34%); multi-tool (26%); wire (26%); bivy bag (17%); water bottle (15%); frying pan (11%).

That site sets them out two ways. One is a graph, and the other is a breakdown of each year.

[image: Graph]
[image: Top part of list]
[image: Bottom part of list]